# Angular Sync 2 input fields like in google translate

Tags: angular

So I have task whre I need to have 2 inputs one is  with English letters other is in different letters in my case Bulgarian so when I write in one input the other should display same word in different letters for example: hello : хелло how can I do that. It should look like google translate for refference.

I made custom pipe but i cant sync both inputs with it also i tried to make object and give it Onkey inputs but it doesnot works

Answer (score 0):

I would use a reactive form and subscribe to the `valueChanges` observable of the field you're translating. Once the translation is complete, you can set/patch the value of the other field, or simply display the form's `translation` value somewhere in your component.

Example:

```js
class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  form: FormGroup;
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      source: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required ]),
      translation: new FormControl(''),
    });

    const translationControl = this.form.get('source') as FormControl;

    this.subscription = this.form.get('source')
                                 .valueChanges
                                 .subscribe(value => {
                                   const translation = translate(value);

                                   translationControl.setValue(translation);
                                  });

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```